# Mongod is not working in Jenkins with "Unable to create/open lock file"

Tags: mongodb, jenkins, redhat

I am using mongo for local integration tests, which has been working for weeks on a few developer's systems. The test suite starts mongo and prepares it for the test.  I decided to use the same testing on Jenkins, but Jenkins fails to start mongod.  We are using the command   `mongod --dbpath tmp/data/db` before each test run.  In Jenkins we get

```
+ mongod --dbpath tmp/data/db
2015-12-23T10:59:17.291-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=9962 port=27017 dbpath=tmp/data/db 64-bit host=ip-172-31-46-41.us-west-2.compute.internal
2015-12-23T10:59:17.291-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.8
2015-12-23T10:59:17.291-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 83d8cc25e00e42856924d84e220fbe4a839e605d
2015-12-23T10:59:17.291-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-142-160-199 3.10.0-121.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Apr 8 10:48:19 EDT 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-12-23T10:59:17.291-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2015-12-23T10:59:17.291-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "tmp/data/db" } }
2015-12-23T10:59:17.314-0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: tmp/data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2015-12-23T10:59:17.314-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

This is strange since the folders do exist with no files in them and jenkins owns the folders tmp/data/db with the settings `drwxr-xr-x`.  I modified the user jenkins to create a shell and ran the command just like jenkins.  This of course, ran correctly.  Any thoughts on what might be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a permissions issue still, so try running:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p tmp/data/db/
$ sudo chown jenkins tmp/data/db
```

Comment: could also try sudo chown $(whoami) tmp/data/db